# Creating a unique date each time between calls

Tags: java, date, selenium-webdriver, unique

I am writing a Java program using selenium.  I need a function that returns a unique date (mm/dd/yyyy) each time it is called.  The conditions though are that

1. It can never return a date it returned before
2. Is must return a date between 01/01/2071 and 12/31/9999
3. The program will run many times so all program memory will be lost upon termination.  It
   must remember the dates it has returned before.  See next item
4. The easiest way to do this is just keep incrementing the date by 1 day each time, so it 
   needs to remember only 1 date.
5. Unfortunately I cannot write the last date returned to a file in the system to read it 
   next time the program runs because I do not have that ability.
6. The program will be reading data from an Excel spreadsheet so could theoretically store
   the latest date in a cell, but the spreadsheet will be open and it does not seem to 
   have the ability to write to an open file.

Any thoughts?  One thing I thought about doing was using a base date like 1/1/2014 at 00:00:00 and then taking the current date, calculating the number of minutes between the two, and adding this as a number of days to 11/31/2070.  Unfortunately this would work only a couple of years because then there would be more minutes between the two dates than there are days from 1/1/2017 to 12/31/9999

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if your program is called more than about 2,100,000 times?  As you say, you only have a limited number of days before you start to have to repeat a date.

Comment: From what you say, I assume that `Properties` won't be useful because you can't store them.  Does your application have access to the system error log?  You could write a specific message there, and read it each time your application fires up.  I would also suggest talking to your System Administrator to allow access to a specified directory or to a single System property.  You really do need access to some form of persistent storage.

Comment: upon termination can u close the excel sheet ?